# How to change date_range into string with the method in array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
rng=pd.date_range("20150105","20150620",freq="D",tz="Asia/Hong_Kong")
x=[pd.to_datetime(day).strftime(%Y%m%d) for day in rng]
```

Now x is a list of date time string,  How to change  date_range  into  string with the method in array such as the following method ,not to do with list comprehension ,to do with some method in array?

```
a = numpy.arange(10)
a.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
>>> rng = pd.date_range("20150105","20150620",freq="D",tz="Asia/Hong_Kong")
>>> rng.format(formatter=lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
['20150105',
 '20150106',
 '20150107',
 '20150108',
 ...
```